Ag-grid React: "Set Filter" filter type gets reset on rowData update
We are using React ag-grid in a new front-end project. Currently we are attempting to persist a user's filter model to our own back-end service. We accomplish this using the onFilterModelChanged event to post our changes to the back-end. This works fine for every filter type except the Set Filter. The problem occurs when our rowData is updated. When an update occurs the onFilterModelChanged event fires if a Set Filter is active. We end up saving a blank filter model to the backend (a blank filter model is a valid model to save, so we can't filter out that event). The FilterChangedEvent lists the source as columnFilter which is what I would expect for a user initiated change. I have read the Data Updates section of the Set Filter docs. The last section discusses using api.setGridOptions('rowData', newData) to avoid a filter model reset but this does not appear to be an option for the React flavor of ag-grid.
Is there a way to avoid firing the onFilterModelChange event with an active Set Filter in React ag-grid? If not, is there something else I can do to get around this problem?
